# React-Redeux | Can i call connect method of react-redux based upon the condition

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, I am passing brand values  to the component as
   props, based on props value, components call different fecth API
   method in action  fecthOMOrder, fecthSVOrder  respectively. I need 
   to specify same condition in connect, below condition is not working,
   please advise, thanks in advance.

```
if (this.props.brand=="OM")
{
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fecthOMOrder})(OrderList);

}
else
{
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fecthSVOrder })(OrderList);

}
```

Comment: Why not write `fetchOrder` to be more generic and use like `fetchOrder('OM')`?. Either that or import both functions then call the appropriate fetch based on the brand condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `mapDispatchToProps` as well and make it conditional.

```
let mapDispatchToProps;
if (this.props.brand=="OM") {
  mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      fecthOMOrder
    }
  }
}
else {
  mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      fecthSVOrder
    }
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(OrderList);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I cannot able to access my this.props.brand outside the class (sorry I am new to react), Appreciate your help